# Visual studio working with emulator does not see android avd manager?

Tags: android, react-native

Hello windows user run android I'm giving port8081 error when I say java_home jdk can not find the path, but now I did it in order androidstudio avd manager works but I tried the visual studio response

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:629:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:647:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\kiyam\helloNative\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:75:39)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\kiyam\helloNative\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:169:41)
    at then.result (C:\Users\kiyam\helloNative\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:135:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: does `adb devices` show any devices present?

Comment: yes adb looks on the manager and even samsung is working connected on my own phone